# Why is my raspberry pi saying that the button is pressed

Tags: python, button, raspberry-pi, bread-board

I’m trying to create something with my bread and pi but the button is saying that it is pressed and when ever it does say that it is off the LED light blinks off then back on. I’ve tried new buttons and I feel this is a software issue

This is my code

```py
import drivers
import time

display = drivers.Lcd()

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM);

GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(13, 0)

fanOn = False
display.lcd_display_string("Fan: off", 1)   # Write line of text to first line of display


try:
    while True:
        GPIO.output(13, GPIO.input(19))

        if GPIO.input(13) == 0 & fanOn == True:
            GPIO.output(13, 0)
            display.lcd_backlight(1) #turns on backlight
            display.lcd_clear()
            display.lcd_display_string("Fan: off", 1)   # Write line of text to first line of display
            print("off")
            fanOn = False
            time.sleep(0.5)
        elif GPIO.input(13) == 0 & fanOn == False:
            GPIO.output(13, 1)
            display.lcd_backlight(1) #turns on backlight
            display.lcd_clear()
            display.lcd_display_string("Fan: on ", 1)   # Write line of text to first line of display
            print("on")
            fanOn = True
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            continue
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
    display.lcd_clear()
```

Comment: Have you tried another button? which pin are you using for your button?

Comment: @Osian the button is pin 19 and the LED is pin 13

Comment: The code says it should be the other way round.

Comment: @PMF what do you mean

Comment: You are using pin 13 as input in several places. Use a constant to avoid this confusion.